# Cannot move a file using sudo mv

Tags: sudo, directory, mv

I want to move a downloaded folder (called 'Viva' to the themes folder under 
`/usr/share/themes/`.

When I type:

```
sudo mv /desktop/Viva /usr/share/themes
```

it tells me it can't find the `/desktop/Viva` folder.

Comment: This is probably because the file `/desktop/Viva` doesn't exists. Learn to use `ls` to look for files, and remember that Unix file and directory names are case sensitive. For example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-system.htm

Answer (score 5):

There is no directory called `/desktop`.

You may be refering to the directory called `Desktop` in your home directory. That's your home directory, not the root directory. In a shell command (and in many other applications), your home directory can be represented with the abbreviation `~` (a tilde character). File names are case-sensitive; it's `Desktop`, not `desktop`.

```
sudo mv ~/Desktop/Viva /usr/share/themes
```

Comment: Okay, that does seem to do as you're saying, however, it still tells me that the file doesn't exist. But it certainly does.. any other ideas?

Comment: @user28541 is the Viva folder actually saved to the desktop? You say you downloaded it, so are you sure it's not in `~/Downloads/Viva` which would be the default save location of most downloads.

Comment: Yeah i am sure, i had it in downloads first, but when moving it from there wouldn't work like now, i moved it to the desktop..

Comment: If you don't remember where you put it, run `find ~ -iname viva` (case-insensitive search by file name under your home directory). If you can't find it that way, maybe you put it somewhere else, try `find / -xdev -iname viva`. If that still finds nothing, you're misremembering the name of the directory. If you created `Viva` yesterday or before, you can use `locate -i viva` (`locate` searches a database of file names which is updated nightly).

Comment: What do `ls -l ~/Desktop` says? Paste the output to your question, please.

Comment: There is no tilde `~` before `/Desktop` in the original question. There should be one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no /Desktop directory, but each user account has a $HOME/Desktop directory. You will need to specify the full path to the file, and because you are using sudo you cannot use a ~ abbreviation or it will look in the root users /Desktop directory which doesn't exist rather than the user's home directory.

## Steps:

1. In terminal type `sudo mv /home/user-name/desktop/Viva /usr/share/themes`. You will need to substitute `user-name` with the user name of the account you are using.

## Notes:

1. When copying files that don't require the use of sudo you can abbreviate the path of the current users home directory with a ~ in front. Eg: cd ~/Desktop. This only works for the user account under which the command is run. So if user Example runs the command then it will look in /home/Example/Desktop.

Comment: This is probably it. I overlooked the use of sudo... And the fact that it squashes environment  variables so $HOME points to the wrong place. +1.

Comment: Your remark about `~` not being usable is wrong. The `~` is expanded by the calling shell, before running sudo. Furthermore, under Ubuntu, even `sudo sh -c 'echo ~'` would show the home directory of the calling user, because sudo is configured to preserve `HOME`.